# Give read/write permission of group files to a user

Tags: linux, setfacl

How can I use setfacl to allow a user to have read/write permission on the home directory of any user that belongs to a certain group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want **user1** to have access to the home directory of all users in the **group1** group.

I don't think that you can do that with one magic command.  The best you can do is add an ACL to each home directory that you want **user1** to have access to.

`for dir in /home/user1 /home/user2 /home/user3 ; do setfacl -R -m u:user1:rwx $dir ; done`

You could put a script in place to run that every day.  It could look for all members **group1** and then execute the *setfacl* command on their home directory.

I think with more explanation of what you're looking for, I could provide a better answer.  I am thinking proper group permissions and umask settings would take care of this much more easily than setfacl.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pretty much that's what I'm trying to do. I thought of setfacl since it looked like the right tool for the job but if you know how to do this with groups and umask, please do explain.

Comment: If all the users can have the same primary group, then make user1 a member of that group as well, and set all the umasks to 0002.  This relies on your users not changing their default umask.  The more I think about it, the more setfacl is probably the more reliable way.

Comment: Ok thanks, you missed a -m in the setfacl command btw

Comment: I don't use ACLs very much...I'm not terribly familiar with setfacl's syntax.

Comment: You can also use `d:u:user1:rwX` to set an inheritable default ACL on directories that will make new files automatically get `u:user1:rw` and new directories get `u:user1:rwx,d:u:user1:rwX`