# Correctly assigning permissions & groups

Tags: nginx, permissions, users, chmod, groups

So my nginx is using `www-data:www-data`, and I want to deploy files to my server with Beanstalk through sftp properly.

So I've created an user called `beanstalk` and added him to `www-data` group.

```
$ id beanstalk
uid=1000(beanstalk) gid=1000(beanstalk) groups=1000(beanstalk),33(www-data)

$ groups beanstalk
beanstalk : beanstalk www-data
```

Now that I've run a script that generates `subby.site.net` and sets it's permissions to be `755 www-data:www-data` ( EasyEngine ), I'm ready to deploy my thing, but here is the thing:

```
beanstalk@site.net:/var/www/subby.site.net.net$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-sr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 08:50 .
drwxrwsr-x 26 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 09:32 ..
drwxr-sr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 08:50 htdocs
drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 14 08:50 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 3052 Nov 14 08:50 wp-config.php

beanstalk@site.net:/var/www/subby.site.net.net$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

If I do `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/subby.site.net`, I can create that test directory with `beanstalk` user, but I don't think 775 is the correct way of setting web-server permissions, or am I wrong ?

Comment: Hi. Looks like a job for ACLs. At the moment the group can't write in this directory. Only the owner.

Comment: Hi Eamonn, What should I look for in ACL ? I assume it's Access Control Lists - can you point me some good reading material about it that would be related to my scenario ?

Comment: `apropos ACL` you want `man setfacl` and `man getfacl`. There are other ways of managing a public web site without mangling permissions, for example [A git based web workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)

Comment: check this out http://serverfault.com/questions/515702/give-read-write-permission-of-group-files-to-a-user

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your beanstalk thing runs with `beanstalk:www-data` user/group when trying to access your `www-data:www-data` owned directory tree (the beanstalk group is useless here).

Since the user `beanstalk` has not rights there (the files/directories are owned by the `www-data` user, the permissions are decided at the group level (the files/directories belong to the `www-data` group which beanstalk belongs to).
The 'other' permissions might be used too.

However, when you use `755` permissions on a directory, the 'group' and 'other' permission are `5`, which means `r-x`. Thus your beanstalk program is able to open (execute) the directory and read its contents... but cannot create files there!

The problem I see with the ACL solution you have been provided with is that those ACLs need to be refreshed everytime new files/directories are created.

What you could do, using properties of the ext filesystem itself, is either:

- Make your tree owned by `beanstalk:www-data` with default rights: the user is by default the only one allowed to write (`755` for directories and `644` for files). SInce you just need beanstalk to do that, that is fine! nginx and any Web server program usually only need to *read* files and navigate through the directory tree, so making them part of the `www-data` is enough. To ensure subsequent directories creation have the www-data group automatically, you could set the `setgid` flag on your existing directories, already set with the `beanstalk:www-data` owner pair. Every new file/directory created will now be owned by `beanstalk:www-data`!
- Add the write permission for the group to every created directories. However, once again, the default mask will create directories with `755` you will need to transform manually to `775`... If your Web bcontent directory tree is on a dedicated partition, you could change the default permissions mask so it is `775`, which is a limitation. Another downside is that now every application belonging to the `www-data` group will be able to write data i nthe directory tree... that includes nginx, and potentially any backend application. I find it bad to allow them 'open-bar' permissions: think of when they will get injected somehow, they could deface/erase everything at will!